# use of "personal" when referring to a collective body

Tags: word-usage

in a document can it be stated that "The Board of Directors Board of Directors wishes to honor -------- and to express its sincere personal appreciation and gratitude for his excellent service, dedication and …

Comment: Perhaps 'unanimous'?

Comment: I imagine the "Board of Directors Board of Directors" might raise a few eyebrows before they get to the "personal" part.

Comment: And honor is missing a 'u' where I come from.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey  But not where I come from.

Answer (score 1):

We would use 'personal' when discussing something "relating or belonging to a single or particular person rather than to a group or an organization". One person can express their own personal opinion or feelings, such as appreciation; a group or body cannot. They might express appreciation that was collective ("shared by every member of a group of people").

[Personal](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/personal)

[Collective](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/collective)